# Remove glued gasket from swing-top bottle stoppers

Tags: adhesive, removal, porcelain

I would like to remove gaskets around ceramic/porcelain swing-top bottle stoppers (also called  [flip-top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-top) or Quillfeldt stopper).  [image]

It cannot be cut easily and seems strongly glued. I tried boiling water to soften the glue, but it did not work. I would be interested to perform the operation on about 60 stoppers.

Comment: I've never seen one that IS glued. It's more likely that the rubber has simply "fused" to the ceramic under constant pressure. Use a solvent that will attack the rubber, like MEK or maybe acetone (fingernail polish remover).

Comment: I am indeed not sure it glued, I seen the possibility on other forums. I will try acetone

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about opening bottles, not [diy.se] as described in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen one that was glued. It may be stuck from the liquid that was in the bottle.

Soak it in hot water and Just work it back and forth to loosen and pull over the nub.

Comment: I left some in boiling water, did not seem to work, but I will try longer